# Joomla Update Install: Error SQL Duplicate entry

Tags: sql, joomla

when I try to update joomla I get the folowing duplicate entry error: Not sure how to fix it and have searched google etc to no avail. Any help appreictaed thanks.

```
Warning

JInstaller: :Install: Error SQL Duplicate entry '458' for key 'PRIMARY'
Files Update: SQL error file DB function failed with error number 1062 
Duplicate entry '458' for key 'PRIMARY'

SQL =
INSERT INTO `#__extensions` (`extension_id`, `name`, `type`, `element`, 
`folder`, `client_id`, `enabled`, `access`, `protected`, `manifest_cache`, 
`params`, `custom_data`, `system_data`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, 
`ordering`, `state`) VALUES
(458, 'plg_quickicon_phpversioncheck', 'plugin', 'phpversioncheck', 
'quickicon', 0, 1, 1, 1, '', '', '', '', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0);
```

Thanks again for any assistance solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will guide you to a solution:

https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=949825

Comment: Thanks Sven, The site actually upgraded successfully but then gave the error as well. I went to the database and clicked the FIX button as you suggest as it was showing out of date and the site now functions fine. Thanks again. Much appreciated

Comment: Thanks Sven, much appreciated and apologies, I did forget.